# How to access KeyValuePair collection as JSON array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, asp.net-core, keyvaluepair

I'm making Ajax calls to a page in ASP.NET Core 3.1.

The response is a `JsonResult` whose `Value` property is an instance of a custom class, itself  containing various string and collection properties.

One of these collections is a `Dictionary<string, string>`, which I can then access in JavaScript along the following lines:

```
var dictionary = response.DictionaryObj;

for (key in dictionary) {
    DoSomeStuff(key, dictionary[key]);
}
```

However another of these collections requires a non-unique 'key', and is currently a `List<KeyValuePair>`

This ends up in JavaScript as an array of objects, which I can access like this:

```
var kvps = response.KvpList;

for (i = 0; i < kvps.length; i++) {
   var kvp = kvps[i];
   DoSomeMoreStuff(kvp.key, kvp.value);
}
```

The latter seems far less elegant - is there a way of packaging up the KeyValuePairs in a way that would let me use the former syntax?

Comment: @Tx_monster The key can, yes.  The keys represent actions, and the values are each a concatenated list of arguments.  So the key can appear many times, with different values.  The JS iterates through the list, unpacks the args and then carries out the actions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an object and you want to iterate through its properties, then we can use `Object.entries` method to [get an array of a given object's own enumerable string-keyed property [key, value] pairs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries),  and then just use loop `foreach`:

```js
let input =  { "workType": "NDB To Nice", "priority": 5, "name": "Joseph", "lastName": "Skeet" }


const fooFunctiion = (key, value) => {
  console.log(`key: ${key}, value ${value}` )
}

Object.entries(input).forEach(([k, v]) => {
    fooFunctiion(k, v)
});
```

If you have an array of objects, then you can use `foreach` method:

```js
let input = [
  { "workType": "NDB To Nice", "priority": 5 },
  { "workType": "PDAD", "priority": 0 },
  { "workType": "PPACA", "priority": 0 },
  { "workType": "Retrigger", "priority": "5" },
  { "workType": "Special Intake Request Intake", "priority": "7" }
];

const fooFunction = (obj, index) => {
  console.log('obj: ', obj, index )
}

input.forEach((obj, ind) =>
    fooFunction(obj, ind)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

For `Dictionary<string, string>` you can use [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

For `List<KeyValuePair>` [object destructuring](https://javascript.info/destructuring-assignment#object-destructuring)

```js
const dictionaryObj = {
    a: 'somestring',
    b: 42,
};

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(dictionaryObj)) {
    console.log(`${key}: ${value}`); // DoSomeStuff(key, value)
}

console.log('===========================================');

const kvpList = [
    { key: '1', value: 'v1' },
    { key: '2', value: 'v2' },
    { key: '3', value: 'v3' },
];

for (const { key, value } of kvpList) {
    console.log(`${key}: ${value}`); // DoSomeMoreStuff(key, value)
}
```